# Is this step in my proof legitimate?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

I’m trying Exercise 6.2.8 from the Bartle and Sherbert Real Analysis book, which says the following:

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$. Show that if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}f’(x)=A$, then $f’(a)$ exists and equals $A$. [*Hint*: Use the definition of $f’(a)$ and the Mean Value Theorem.]

Here’s what I’ve tried, and I’ve marked with $(*)$ the step I am unsure about:

Suppose $x\in(a,b)$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $(a,x)$ and continuous on $[a,x]$. Therefore, we may use the Mean Value Theorem to say that for some $c\in(a,x),$$f(x)-f(a)=f’(c)(x-a).$ Then since $x\neq a$, we may divide both sides by $x-a$ to obtain $f’(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Taking the limit on both sides, we get
$(*)\,A=\displaystyle\lim_{c\to a}f’(c)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f’(a)$, so $f’(a)$ exists and equals $A.$

I’m just wondering if $(*)$ is legitimate. On one hand, it doesn’t seem to make much of a difference to take the limit as $c$ goes to $a$ versus the limit as $x$ goes to $a$ since either way the variable in the argument of $f$ is going to $a$. On the other hand, we did say $c$ was a constant so technically $f’(c)$ is a constant as well, right?

Comment: On the other hand, though, the value of $c$ does seem to depend on the value of $x$, so maybe if I mention that in my proof it would work?

Comment: The proof works because whatever $c=c(x)$ is in the interval $(a,x)$ it does converge to $a$ as $x \to a$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ok cool, I’ll just make sure I explicitly mention that $c$ depends on $x$. Thanks for the help!